# Syntaxhighlighter is not working

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, stylesheet, code-formatting

I am using the [syntaxhighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/), but it is not working. You can see the page : http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/templates1.htm. Any ideas?

**EDIT** : It is working okay now but But now a strange scroll is coming as shown below.
[image]

Comment: There seems to be other differences between the two pages you've listed.  could you edit template 1 so that the only difference is the main css file?  Perhaps the stylesheet editor uses similar classnames and id names as you've put in template 1.

Comment: @Ape-inago the other template looks different because I took all the id out of all the <div>s. Othersie, they are essentially same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your html into a page on my site. I didn't change much. Here are all the changes that I made:

1. Changed the references to use my copy of SyntaxHighlighter. This was only necessary to make it work behind my domain.
2. Changed the reference to your css from a relative path to a fully qualified path. Yes I am leaching your css from you...hope you don't mind ;)
3. Removed the 'autoloader' stuff. I think this is the big issue.

Here is a link to a working page:

http://bobcravens.com/demos/test/syntax.html

View source on it and you should be able to make modifications to your original.

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: Thanks, it saved me lot of work. But now a strange scroll is coming as shown above.